How to copy a matplotlib / seaborn image to memory like a screenshot
I am plotting a heatmap using seaborn. I want to copy this image directly to clipboard like a screenshot. I am not able to find any solution to get around this. My current solution is as follows
def copy_image_to_memory(image: plt.figure, close: bool = False) -> None:
    from io import BytesIO
    from subprocess import run
    
    plt.savefig(buffer := BytesIO(), format='png', facecolor='white')
    buffer.seek(0)
    
    run('pbcopy', input=buffer.read(), check=True, shell=True)
    print("Image copied to memory")
    
    if close:
        print("Closing image")
        plt.close()
    else:
        print("Image not closed")


Problem with this solution is that it copies the image as a byte string. This cannot be copied as a file or a screenshot.
Any help is appreciated.

On a Mac you might use python to "shell out" to pbcopy.
Can python send text to the Mac clipboard
Alternatively on a windows machine you might try the win32clipboard module.
How do I read text from the Windows clipboard in Python?
I suspect the linux solution is a google away, as these were.
